# How to check if checkbox exists PHP

Tags: php, http-post, isset

This looks like a possible duplicate but there are a lot questions on how to check if a checkbox is checked and I couldnt find any about checking if a checkbox even exists. So please be so kind and answer this silly question

I tried: 
`if (isset($_POST['box']))` 
returns false if the box exists but is not checked

```
if (is_null($_POST['box']))
```

error (Undefined offset: 1) if the box exists and is not checked

Are there other functions to try ?
Any advice for a workaround ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `if (array_key_exists('box', $_POST))` will accomplish it

Comment: in other words if(!empty(...)) checkbox is checked (assuming the value isn't zero or null

Answer (score 0):

Browsers only submit checkboxes that are checked. So if `$_POST['box']` exists (`isset($_POST['box']) === true`), the checkbox was checked. And if it does not exist, the checkbox was not checked.